# Dynamic vector of names: increasing 3 to n

Tags: r, quantitative-finance

I would like to extend this code from {x.a, x.b, x.c} to {x.a, ... , x.n} where n is defined as length(names).

```
names = c("a", "b" , "c")
set.seed(123)
x.nsim = 5000
x.a = runif(x.nsim, min=-1.5, max=1.5)
x.b = runif(x.nsim, min=-1.5, max=1.5)
x.c = 1 - x.a - x.b

for (i in 1:x.nsim) {
  z.vec = c(x.a[i], x.b[i], x.c[i])
  points(z.vec^3, z.vec, cex=0.1)
}
```

I attempted to do this extension. Any hints?

```
a<-NULL
for (name in names){
  #x<-paste("x.",name,"[i]", sep="", collapse="")
  a<-cbind(a, paste("x.",name,"[i]", sep="", collapse=""))
  a
}
a
z.vec <- NULL
for (i in 1:x.nsim){
  for (j in 1:length(names)){
    z.vec <- cbind(z.vec, a[j])
    points(z.vec^3, z.vec, cex=0.1)
  }
}
```

Comment: You should use data structures instead of sequential names. Use vectors, matrices, or lists depending on the dimensionality of the objects you are trying to name sequentially.

Comment: Probably there should be `1:x.nsim` instead of `1:length(x.nsim)`, because  it's just `1:1`.

Answer (score 0):

Like Gregor has commented, you should use data structures here. Since we have lots of vectors of the same length and type (and origin) it is natural to use matrices here.
Let's set some initial parameters:

```
nsim <- 5000
n <- 10
```

As I understand from what you've written, we should sample `(n-1)` vectors of length `nsim` from the uniform distribution on `[-1.5, 1.5]`. Instead of simulating one vector after another we can do it more quickly by simulating `(n-1)*nsim` values and then putting them into matrix with `(n-1)` columns:

```
m <- matrix(runif((n - 1)*nsim, -1.5, 1.5), ncol = n - 1)
```

Column number `n` is `1 - [sum of first (n-1) columns]` (again as I understand).

```
m <- cbind(m, 1 - rowSums(m))
```

Now you can get your `z.vec` number `i` just as `m[i,]`.

Comment: @ Iaroslav Domin thanks this is cool. are there other ways to solve it (pedagogically)?

Comment: Sure there are. But from what I can think up here, everything looks uglier and less optimised.